# Closing Parent window using child window.!

Tags: mfc

I am new to MFC(vc++) and interested in learning it.I am having a parent window and a child window,I want to close both parent and child window, when  a button is pressed from child window.Please help me in this.
thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: Please show your code so far. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child window is destroyed when the parent is destroyed. This is the normal behavior

If you call

```
GetParent()->DestroyWindow();
```

from the child, the parent gets destroyed and the child to. But take, care. A modal dialog is not closed with DestroyWindow. EndDIalog is the correct way. Also message and command Routing makes is unnecessary to handle the destruytion from the parent from a handler within the child.

As already written: Show us more of your code and your problem.

Comment: What code? To use the Dialog in another CPP file you just include the Header declare the Dialog and call DoModal. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I have Created a dialog box in CPayment.cpp. To call the dialog box in another .cpp file I have used the following code,                CPayment CPay;                                           CPay.Domodal();                   On that modal box i am having two buttons,one is 'OK' and another one is 'Cancel'.on clicking OK the dialog box is closing.For that I used 'POSTMESSAGE(WM_CLOSE)',But on clicking 'Cancel' button I need to close the dialog box and parent window of that Dialog box.

Comment: DOn't Change the code in the Dialog. The Dialog Closes always when clincking IDOK oder IDCACNEL. Check the returncode od DoModal. If DoModal Returns IDCANCEL do whatever you Need to destroy the parent. Either calling again EndDialog, or DestroyWindow or posting WM_CLOSE... You didn't told us, what Kind of window the parent is.

Answer (score 0):

[DoModal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx) will return either IDOK or IDCANCEL based upon the button clicked. So use it.
For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx

*Note: In MFC only the identifier of the class will begin with 'C' not the object.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
```